# Inductor/Transformer core design - reducing losses from eddy currents

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

From what I know, the key to reducing losses due to eddy currents in a core is to reduce the path that they take, as is shown in this [diagram illustrating solid vs. laminated cores](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/Laminering_av_k%C3%A4rna.svg) (courtesy of Wikipedia).

Would taking this one step further and making the core a bundle of wires/rods instead of a stack of laminations reduce the losses further? If so, then why aren't there any commercial designs using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stands between each lamination ? Isolator. If you switch from lamination to wires, you'll get much more isolator, and therefore less metal in the same volume of core. Doing so, you'll get a less efficient core, you'll have to increase its size, increasing cost, wire length on the coils, losses in the wires and that's often a bigger drawback than the benefit in metal losses reduction. I'm also doubtful about the mechanical resistance of such core.

Comment: In addition, rods would be difficult to use in making the pieces of a split-core transformer mate together with minimum reluctance.